# fullscreen video background script

Tags: looking-for-a-script, video, youtube

I'm looking for a script or a tutorial that allows me to stream for example a youtube video in fullscreen, but not flash because I want it  to work on mobile devices too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery HTML5 video background with demo page take a look http://www.georgepaterson.com/2011/06/13/jquery-html5-video-background-1-0-0/

Comment: Wow!!!... Just, wow...